# Canvas Background not clearing

Tags: javascript, canvas, background

It seems like a very simple problem and i must just be overlooking something but with this code:

```
window.onresize = function(){
  init.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  init.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
}
var init = {
  canvas: new Object(),
  ctx: new Object(),
  constructCanvas: function(){
    this.canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    this.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    this.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  }
}
init.constructCanvas();

var a = 20;
var b = 20;
init.ctx.lineWidth = 4;
function loop(){
  init.ctx.fillStyle = "Blue";
  init.ctx.fillRect(0,0,init.canvas.width,init.canvas.height);
  init.ctx.moveTo(a,b);
  init.ctx.lineTo(a+=9,b);
  init.ctx.stroke();
}
setInterval(loop,100);
```

What should be happening is I get little line segments of length 9 then when the next call happens that one should clear and another line segment should be placed down at the end of the previous one but what happens instead is I just get one long line and the fillRect call seems to do nothing.

Comment: The answer will fix your problem, but you are doing some stuff wrong. Use `requestAnimationFrame` to call the loop function. Creating the object in `init` for `canvas` and `ctx` properties is redundant and you overwrite them anyway. Remove the two lines as you create them in the `constructCanvas` function. Also `new Object()` is the same as `{}`. You dont use window in `window.setInterval` so why use window in `innerWidth`, `innerHeight`, and `onresize` . `window` is always the default scope, you should never have to use it unless you are forcing a global variable.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the many Canvas problems that happen if you don't use `beginPath()`:

The canvas does get cleared properly. However you never clear the path, so you always redraw the whole line, not just the section you want. By calling `moveTo` and `lineTo` you are merely adding the next section to the already created Path, that is then drawn on `stroke`. You need to begin a new path instead:

```
function loop(){
  init.ctx.fillStyle = "Blue";
  init.ctx.fillRect(0,0,init.canvas.width,init.canvas.height);

  init.ctx.beginPath():
  init.ctx.moveTo(a,b);
  init.ctx.lineTo(a+=9,b);
  init.ctx.stroke();
}
```

Comment: Ok, so without calling beginPath is the call moveTo effectively being ignored?

Comment: No it isn't, yet it didn't change anything effectively before. Imagine the line of a brush on that canvas. `moveTo` moves the brush to the position, where the last line ended. However, the brush was sitting there anyways already, since you haven't started a new path yet. `moveto` doesn't create a new path, it just lifts the brush and moves it to a new position, without drawing a line in between. When you use 'beginPath' the information about the last brushes position is lost and you have to move it this time around.